# when I declare next view controller with guard let, button doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit

I was making a simple sign-up views and I wanted to present next view with modal by button. but when I declared next view instance with 'guard let', button didn't work at all.
and then I declared it by just 'let', it works.

can you guys give me the reason why it worked in 'let', and didn't in 'guard let'?

This is first view's code.

```
    let signUpButton : UIButton = {
        let lButtonSettings = UIButton()
        lButtonSettings.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        lButtonSettings.setTitle("Sign Up", for: .normal)
        lButtonSettings.setTitleColor(.systemRed, for: .normal)
        lButtonSettings.setTitleColor(.systemIndigo, for: .selected)
        lButtonSettings.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pressButton), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        return lButtonSettings
    }()


    @IBAction func pressButton(_ sender : UIButton) {
        guard let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "SecondViewController") else {return}
        //let viewController = SecondViewController() -> worked code
        viewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.fullScreen
        present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

and this is SceneDelegate code.

```
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        
        guard let scene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        window = UIWindow(windowScene: scene)
        let mainViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController())
        window?.rootViewController = mainViewController
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

I deleted main.storyboard to practice development without storyboards.

maybe that could be a problem, but I want transparent answer.

Comment: You deleted the storyboard, so why did you expect `storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "SecondViewController")` to give you anything at all?

Comment: `self.storyboard` is nil since you removed the storyboard. Check  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621399-storyboard Why should it work then? It's unclear.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to program without storyboards, don't use any storyboard functions. (like your call to `storyboard?.instantiateViewController()`. Don't do that.)

You'll need to implement an initializer in your view controller that creates it some other way. (`init(frame:)` would work.) Then in that view controller you'll need to implement the `loadView()` method. and create your view controller's views there.

Comment: Slight aside, and something I've never got a good handle on: unless you are providing a custom root view, is there any benefit in creating your views in the `loadView()` rather than as lazy properties assembled in `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: @flanker I don't understand what you say. what's load view? I also used viewDidload .

Comment: @Hide_In_Swift, if you don’t create your view controller’s view hierarchy from a storyboard or nibfile, you need to create it some other way. There is a function loadView() defined for view controllers. If your view controller does not have a storyboard/nibfile, the system will try to call your `loadView()` function. There are other ways to create your view hierarchy, but first try creating your views in `loadView()`.

Comment: Bottom line: When you delete your storyboard, your call to `storyboard?.instantiateViewController()` is going to fail because there is no storyboard to call. That’s why your code isn’t working.

Comment: @DuncanC then, when I erase main.storyboard file, using function loadView() is the best way to re-create view hierarchy instead of using viewDidLoad.

Comment: @DuncanC did I get it right?

Comment: Building your view hierarchy in loadView is the most straightforward way to do it. As Flanker alludes to, it is also possible to set up all your other views as lazy properties and add them to your view hierarchy in `viewDidLoad()` but that is likely more confusing for a novice developer.